# How to use router guard in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am have been trying to get this to work, but it doesn't seem to work. I am trying to use the beforeRouteUpdate in my component in nuxt. What I want is for an api request to be made when I try to leave that page to another page. Here is my code;

```
<template>
  <div>
      //code here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    console.log('Before update')
  },
}
</script>
```

In the code above, I am trying to log a message to the console when the route is updated, and nothing seems to happen. I tried making a request to the server when the route changes, that doesn't also work.
Tried using this other way;

```
<template>
  <div>
      //code here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      console.log('Route path')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

It still doesn't work. The current path is `http://localhost:3000/cart`. I am trying to console.log a message when the path changes to `http://localhost:3000/` or something else.
I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

**I am using console.log in this case for simplicity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `beforeRouteUpdate` use `beforeRouteLeave`:

```
<template>
  <div>
      //code here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    console.log('Route Leave')
  },
}
</script>
```